# Navigate through input fields with keyboard

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface

When I user clicks on a link, a div Is shown up. Inside this div, there are some input-fields, checkboxes. Some of them are selected by default.

The thing I want to accomplish Is that when the div is opened, I want to give the user the ability to tab/nagivate between this checkboxes directly.

Now, I must hit the tab-button a few time to get the first checkbox "on focus", so I can start navigate. I want to do this directly when the user opens the div, without hitting the tab button twice.

I have tried to simulate a click-event like this:

```
$('#categoryBasic').click(function () {
    $('#DatabasesValue-1').click();
});
```

But this don't work.

Here is the div that opens when you click on the link:

```
<div id="divInputBasic" class="divInput">
    <div id="basicContainer1">
        <div class="basicContainer1 left" style="float: left; width: 35%">
            <label class="small-space-bottom inline-block bold-text">Databas</label>
            <div id="divValueDatabases" class="checkboxButtonGroupSelector">
                @{
                    foreach (var database in PageData["Databases"])
                    {
                        System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
                        sb.Append(
                            "<input " +
                            "id=\"DatabasesValue-" + database.Id + "\" " +
                            "name=\"DatabasesValue\" " +
                            "type=\"radio\" " +
                            "value=\"" + database.Id + "\" " +
                            (database.Checked ? "checked=\"checked\" " : string.Empty) +
                            (database.Disabled ? "disabled=\"disabled\" " : string.Empty) +
                            "title=\"" + database.Description + "\"" +
                            " />" +
                            "<label " +
                            "for=\"DatabasesValue-" + database.Id + "\" " +
                            "title=\"" + database.Description + "\"" +
                            ">" + database.Description + "</label>" +
                            "<br />"
                            );

                        @Html.Raw(sb);
                    }
                }
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="basicContainer1" style="float: left; width: 35%">
            <label class="small-space-bottom inline-block bold-text">Källa</label>
            <div id="divValueDataSources" class="checkboxButtonGroupSelector small-space-bottom">
                @{
                    foreach (var dataSource in PageData["DataSources"])
                    {
                        System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
                        sb.Append(
                            "<input " +
                            "id=\"DataSourcesValue-" + dataSource.Id + "\" " +
                            "name=\"DataSourcesValue\" " +
                            "type=\"radio\" " +
                            "value=\"" + dataSource.Id + "\" " +
                            (dataSource.Checked ? "checked=\"checked\" " : string.Empty) +
                            (dataSource.Disabled ? "disabled=\"disabled\" " : string.Empty) +
                            "title=\"" + dataSource.Description + "\"" +
                            " />" +
                            "<label " +
                            "for=\"DataSourcesValue-" + dataSource.Id + "\" " +
                            "title=\"" + dataSource.Description + "\"" +
                            ">" + dataSource.Description + "</label>" +
                            "<br />"
                            );

                        @Html.Raw(sb);
                    }
                }
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="basicContainer1 left" style="float: left; width: 20%">
            <label class="small-space-bottom inline-block bold-text">Nivå</label>
            <div id="divValueDataSelections" class="checkboxButtonGroupSelector">
                @{
                    foreach (var dataSelection in PageData["DataSelections"])
                    {
                        System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
                        sb.Append(
                            "<input " +
                            "id=\"DataSelectionsValue-" + dataSelection.Id + "\" " +
                            "name=\"DataSelectionsValue\" " +
                            "type=\"radio\" " +
                            "value=\"" + dataSelection.Id + "\" " +
                            (dataSelection.Checked ? "checked=\"checked\" " : string.Empty) +
                            (dataSelection.Disabled ? "disabled=\"disabled\" " : string.Empty) +
                            "title=\"" + dataSelection.Description + "\"" +
                            " />" +
                            "<label " +
                            "for=\"DataSelectionsValue-" + dataSelection.Id + "\" " +
                            "title=\"" + dataSelection.Description + "\"" +
                            ">" + dataSelection.Description + "</label>" +
                            "<br />"
                            );

                        @Html.Raw(sb);
                    }
                }
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="basicContainer2 left" style="float: left; width: 20%">
            <label class="small-space-bottom inline-block bold-text">Olycks-ID</label>
                <div id="accidentField">
                    <input type="text" name="accidentId" id="accidentId"/>
                </div>    
          </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `focus` the input after triggering `click`:

```
$('#categoryBasic').click(function () {
    $('#DatabasesValue-1').click();
    $('#DatabasesValue-1').find(':checkbox').first().focus();
});
```

check the snippet:

```js
$('#categoryBasic').click(function() {
  $('#DatabasesValue-1').show().find(':checkbox').first().focus();
});
```

```css
#DatabasesValue-1 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='categoryBasic'>click</div>
<div id='DatabasesValue-1'>
  <input type='checkbox'>
  <input type='checkbox'>
  <input type='checkbox'>
  <input type='checkbox'>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, but the checkbox just get selected. When I manually clicks In a checkbox, a dotted square Is visible around the checkbox. Then I can navigate with the tab. I want to simulate this "dotted square" when the div Is visible.

Comment: @Jay: It seems that the div that opens must be In "focus". Because when I click on the div after It has been open, and then click on the tab, It works.

Comment: @Bryan Is the element is clicked `categoryBasic` is this `DatabasesValue-1` child of it?

Comment: categoryBasic Is just a simple link.

Comment: can you update your question with the html structure you have? because this way it should work. i guess there is something else which is causing issue.

Comment: @Jay: Check my updated question. As you can see, the checkboxes are generated by a loop. #DatabaseValue-1 Is one of the generated checkboxes.

Comment: @Jay: I noticed that when I remove the code that makes the div draggable, It works. But when I use the .draggable(); It does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `tabindex` property? [tabindex docs](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_tabindex.asp)

Or you can change your code to this

```
$('#categoryBasic').click(function () {
    $('#DatabasesValue-1').trigger('click');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `focus`, see [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Arg0n/zykh637e/1/) fiddle:

JavaScript

```
$('#categoryBasic').click(function () {
    $('.hidden').show();
    $("#DatabasesValue-1").focus();
});
```

HTML

```
<button id="categoryBasic">
    Click me!
</button>
<div class="hidden">
    <input type="text"/><br/>
    <input type="text"/><br/>
    <input type="checkbox" id="DatabasesValue-1"/>
    <label for="DatabasesValue-1">Text 1</label><br/>
    <input type="checkbox" id="DatabasesValue-2"/>
    <label for="DatabasesValue-1">Text 2</label><br/>
    <input type="checkbox" id="DatabasesValue-3"/>
    <label for="DatabasesValue-1">Text 3</label><br/>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.hidden{
    display: none;
}
```